# ¿Cómo puedo sumar los valores de una columna en SQL-Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Estoy creando un cursor que muestra los resultados de una factura (como se muestra en la imagen de referencia), mi duda es la siguiente ¿cómo puedo sumar los valores que se encuentran dentro de la columna de "cantidad"?

**Código principal**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @id_art1 int, @nom_art varchar(30), @id_art int, @nombre_art varchar(30), @message varchar(80),
        @nomb_art20 varchar(20), @id_fact int, @cant_art int, @cant_esp int;

PRINT '--------  Ventas x Producto Report --------'

DECLARE cte_prod_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT id_art, nom_art FROM articulo -- WHERE suspendido = 1
       ORDER BY id_art;

OPEN cte_prod_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cte_prod_cursor  INTO @id_art1, @nom_art

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT ' '
    SELECT @message = '----- Facturas del Producto: ' + cast (@id_art1 as varchar)
                     + ' ' + @nom_art
    PRINT @message 
    
    ---------Primera parte

    ---------Segunda parte

    DECLARE prod_fact_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT  fa.id_fact,art.id_art, art.nom_art, det_fact.cant_art
    FROM det_fact join factura fa on det_fact.id_fact = fa.id_fact
                  join articulo art on art.id_art = @id_art1 and det_fact.id_art = art.id_art
    OPEN prod_fact_cursor
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM prod_fact_cursor INTO @id_fact, @id_art,
                                          @nombre_art, @cant_art
    IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 
        PRINT '      << No Hay Productos Facturados >>'     
    ELSE
        PRINT ' Fact. Prod Nombre             Cantidad'     
    
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        set @cant_esp = 20 -- Len(@nombre_art)
        set @nomb_art20 = ''
        set @nomb_art20 = @nombre_art + space(@cant_esp);
        SELECT @message = '   ' + cast (@id_fact as varchar) + '    ' + 
                          cast (@id_art as varchar) +
                          '  ' + @nomb_art20 + ' ' + CAST( @cant_art as varchar)
        PRINT @message
        
        FETCH NEXT FROM prod_fact_cursor INTO @id_fact, @id_art,@nombre_art, @cant_art

     END

     CLOSE prod_fact_cursor
     DEALLOCATE prod_fact_cursor
        
     FETCH NEXT FROM cte_prod_cursor  INTO @id_art1, @nom_art
END 


CLOSE cte_prod_cursor;
DEALLOCATE cte_prod_cursor;
```

[image: IMAGEN DE REFERENCIA AL RESULTADO DESEADO]

Se me había ocurrido crear otro cursor y una variable `@suma` en la cual almacenaría el resultado:

```
DECLARE suma_fact_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT  fa.id_fact,art.id_art, art.nom_art, det_fact.cant_art
    FROM det_fact join factura fa on det_fact.id_fact = fa.id_fact
                  join articulo art on art.id_art = @id_art1 and det_fact.id_art = art.id_art
    OPEN suma_fact_cursor
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM suma_fact_cursor INTO @id_fact, @id_art,
                                          @nombre_art, @cant_art
 
        PRINT '                               -------'     
    
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        set @cant_esp = 20 
        SELECT @suma = sum(@cant_art)
        PRINT @suma
        
        FETCH NEXT FROM suma_fact_cursor INTO @id_fact, @id_art,@nombre_art, @cant_art

     END

     CLOSE suma_fact_cursor
     DEALLOCATE suma_fact_cursor
```

Pero no funciona, sería de gran ayuda que me explicaran como poder obtener la suma.

Comment: Saludos. Prueba cambiando `SELECT @suma = sum(@cant_art)` como `SET @suma = @suma + @cant_art)`; esto en el entendido que es un unico dato y no será en caso de ser diversos Productos distintos. No olvides antes de entrar al WHILE Inicializarla en 0 (cero); eventualmente quitar el `PRINT @suma` y en dado caso dejarlo fuera del WHILE para solo una vez se imprima el valor.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr excelente me sirvió mucho gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la suma se podria hacer en la misma consulta, aplicando la funcion sum en el campo cant_art y agragando al final un group by con los campos a los que no le aplicas la funcion sum, la consulta quedria de esta manera:

```
SELECT  fa.id_fact,art.id_art, art.nom_art, sum(det_fact.cant_art) cant_art
    FROM det_fact join factura fa on det_fact.id_fact = fa.id_fact
                  join articulo art on art.id_art = @id_art1 and det_fact.id_art = art.id_art
group by fa.id_fact,art.id_art, art.nom_art
```